# How can i pass parametter on a method who accept request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop

First controller ViewData:

```
public function show(Request $request){
  return $request->url;
}
```

Second controller where I want to pass value to the first controller's show method

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ViewData;

public function pass(){
    $url = "https://abc.xyz"; // the value that i want to pass on first controller

    $viewData= new ViewData;
    $viewData->show(?);
}
```

How can I pass the data from the second controller's pass method to the first controller's show method?

Comment: do u want to pass Request $request in show method always ?

Comment: yes because the method is dependent on another input form

Comment: how is this `pass` method getting called in the first place?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of Request.

```
public function pass(){
    $url = "https://abc.xyz"; // the value that i want to pass on first controller

    $viewData= new ViewData;
     $content = new Request;
     $content->url= $url;
    $viewData->show($content);
}
```

Then in show method.

```
public function show(Request $request){
 if($request->url)
  {
  return $request->url;
   }
}
```